# IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: networking, internet, sockets

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import httplib
import sys

#get http server ip
http_server = sys.argv[0]
#create a connection
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(http_server)

while 1:
    cmd = raw_input('input command (ex. GET index.html): ')
    cmd = cmd.split()

    if cmd[0] == 'exit': #type exit to end it
        break

    #request command to server
    conn.request(cmd[0],cmd[1])

    #get response from server
    rsp = conn.getresponse()

    #print server response and data
    print(rsp.status, rsp.reason)
    data_received = rsp.read()
    print(data_received)

conn.close()
```

### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./client1.py", line 19, in <module>
    conn.request(cmd[0],cmd[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

can any one tell me why that error is coming and can anyone modify the code.
it is a client side code to connect with server

my input is :`GET index.html`

But now my error is

```
File "./client1.py", line 19, in <module>
    conn.request(cmd[0],cmd[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 910, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 947, in _send_request
    self.endheaders()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 904, in endheaders
    self._send_output()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 776, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 735, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 716, in connect
    self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 500, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: What are you providing as input to the question `'input command (ex. GET index.html): '`

Comment: I think that you should ask at [so] with more details about what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you providing as input to the question?

`'input command (ex. GET index.html): '`

The code expects you to input a command like `GET index.html` it then splits that into an array called cmd, Later it tries access index 0 and 1 of the `cmd` array and it finds that there is no cmd[1] or no cmd[0] and cmd[1] probably because of the input it received.

### EDIT

In answer to your second question you need to change your line

`http_server = sys.argv[0]`

to

`http_server = sys.argv[1]`

You then run your script like `./scriptname www.google.co.uk`

Comment: yea, i tried GET index.html but got the different error...

Comment: @Kummi_10 updated for your new problem.

Comment: Thank you for ur answers, But got this new error:                                      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./client1.py", line 7, in <module>
    http_server = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Did you run the script like `./scriptname www.google.co.uk`

Comment: yea,i did run like what u told me to do, but i want the contents of file index.html,rather it displays                                 kumarswamys@kumarswamys-desktop:~$ ./client1.py www.google.com
input command (ex. GET index.html): GET index.html
(302, 'Found')
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>

input command (ex. GET index.html):

Comment: The script is fine now after the edits you just need to learn about HTTP response codes. Have a nice day.

Comment: Thank you very much,i just got the o/p                            ./client1.py localhost
input command (ex. GET index.html): GET /index.html HTTP/1.0
(200, 'OK')
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1>
<p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>
<p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>
</body></html>